# A parameter that accepts a sequence of trait objects and iterate through it multiple times in Rust

Tags: rust, iterator, trait-objects

I have a function that takes a sequence of trait objects and iterates through it multiple times, e.g.,

```rust
trait Animal {
    fn make_noise(&self);
}

fn make_lots_of_noises(animals: &[&dyn Animal]) {
    animals.iter().for_each(|animal| animal.make_noise());
    animals.iter().for_each(|animal| animal.make_noise());
    animals.iter().for_each(|animal| animal.make_noise());
}
```

But I want the function to be able to operate on both borrowed and owned data structures.  Here are the options I tried:

`&[&dyn Animal]` as shown in the code fragment.  Problem: if I have owned trait objects, e.g., `animals: &[Box<dyn Animal>]`, then I have to call `make_lots_of_noises(animals.map(Box::as_ref).collect::<Vec<_>>().as_slice()`, which involves unnecessary allocation on the heap.

`&[&R] where R: AsRef<dyn Animal> + ?Sized`.  Problem: `T` doesn't implement `AsRef<T>`!  It now works with all kinds of smart pointers, but not `&[&dyn Animal]`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Borrow` trait, which does have the `impl Borrow<T> for T` you want.

```rust
use std::borrow::Borrow;

trait Animal {
    fn make_noise(&self);
}

struct Mouse;
impl Animal for Mouse {
    fn make_noise(&self) { /* squeak */ }
}

fn make_lots_of_noises<A: Borrow<dyn Animal>>(animals: &[A]) {
    animals.iter().for_each(|animal| animal.borrow().make_noise());
    animals.iter().for_each(|animal| animal.borrow().make_noise());
    animals.iter().for_each(|animal| animal.borrow().make_noise());
}

fn main() {
    make_lots_of_noises(&[&Mouse as &dyn Animal]);
    make_lots_of_noises(&[Box::new(Mouse) as Box<dyn Animal>]);
}
```